# How to make only one selectable menu option html and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menubar that i am trying to make have only one selectable root listitem at a time. When the user click on one of the top headings, it's respective submenu is displayed. the problem i'm having is when the user clicks one head and moves the mouse up or to the side without ever hovering into the submenu, they can now lick another heading and 2 submenus are displayed at the same time.

If you view it from a mobile phone, then you can click as many root menu items as available, and they all display their respective menus at the same time...NOT ideal.

BUT, if the user clicks a heading, and moves the mouse into the submenu, then everything works, because when they leave that menu to click another root item, the first menu (and its submenus) disappear.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2SC5G/)

Thanks in advance guys/girls.

HTML:

```
<!-- <LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico"> -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/menu.js"></script></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="includes/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="z-index:100;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left: 0;min-width:1000px;">
        <div id="menuJQ">
            <ul class="menuJQ">
                <li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="parent" href="#"><span>Product View</span></a> 
                    <div class="submenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>DevTask Search</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Request Tool</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Search</span></a>
                    <div class="submenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>DevTask Search</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Integrity Query</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Internal DevTasks</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Results</span></a>
                                <div class="submenu">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#" target='_blank'><span>Latest Smoke Results</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" target='_blank'><span>Latest Smoke Results</span></a>
                                            <div class="submenu">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><span>DevTask Search</span></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><span>Integrity Query</span></a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Issues for Stability Team</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* menu::base */
.expand{
    display:block;
}
.collapse{
    display:none;
}
div#menuJQ {
    height: 46px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width:auto;
    /* background: url(../includes/images/right2.png) repeat right 0;  */
    background-color:black; 
}

div#menuJQ ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
div#menuJQ ul.menuJQ {
    padding-right: 0px;
}

div#menuJQ li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    z-index: 9;
    width: auto;
}

div#menuJQ ul ul li {
    z-index: 9;
}
div#menuJQ li div {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 39px;
    left: -18px;
    -left: 4px;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Opera */
    width: 180px;
      margin: 0px 0 0 -4px;
    padding: 0; 
    background: url(../includes/images/submenu-top.png) no-repeat 0px 0;
    -background: url(../includes/images/submenu-top.gif) no-repeat 0px 0; 
}
div#menuJQ ul ul { /*submenu*/
    display:none;
      z-index: 12;
      width: 180px;
    padding: 0px 0px 12px 0px;
    -padding: 0px 0px 3px 0px;    
    background: url(../includes/images/submenu-bottom.png) no-repeat 0px bottom;
    -background: #E4E4E2 none;        
    margin: 14px 0 0 0;   
    -margin: 5px 0 0 0;      
}
div#menuJQ li > div {
    visibility: visible;
}

div#menuJQ a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 38px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    padding-right:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
div#menuJQ span {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 13px Tahoma;
    background: none;
    line-height: 38px;  
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/* menu::level1 */
div#menuJQ a {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    line-height: 38px;
    height: 46px;
    _margin-right: 1px;
    background: none;
    font-weight:bold;    

}
div#menuJQ span {
    font-weight:bold; 
}
div#menuJQ a:hover{
    background-image: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: right -1px;    
    -background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.gif) repeat-x right -1px; 
}
div#menuJQ li.current a,
div#menuJQ ul.menuJQ>li:hover>a {
    background-image: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: right -1px;  
    -background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.gif)  repeat-x right -1px; 
}
div#menuJQ a:hover span{
      color: #000000;
}   
div#menuJQ ul.menuJQ>li:hover>a span {
      color: #000000;
}
div#menuJQ li {}
div#menuJQ li.last { background: none; }


/* menu::level2 */
div#menuJQ ul ul li {
    background-image: url(../includes/images/sep-sub.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul li:hover {
    background-image: url(../includes/images/sub-item-hover.gif);
    background-color: #717171;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a {
      color: #000000;   
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0px;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 166px;
    margin: 0 0px 0 13px;
    background: none;
}

div#menuJQ ul ul a span {
    color: #000000; 
      padding: 0 3px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin:0;    
}
div#menuJQ li.current ul a,
div#menuJQ li.current ul a span {
    background: none;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a:hover {
    background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a:hover span {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a.parent {
  background: url(../includes/images/submenu-pointer.png) no-repeat right top;
  -background: url(../includes/images/submenu-pointer.gif) no-repeat right top;  
  margin-right: -1px;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a.parent span {
  padding-right: 26px;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a.parent:hover {
  background: url(../includes/images/submenu-pointer-hover.gif) no-repeat right top;
  -background: url(../includes/images/submenu-pointer.gif) no-repeat right top;  
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a.parent:hover span {
}
div#menuJQ ul ul span {

    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul li.last { background: none; }
div#menuJQ ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
}

/* menu::level3 */

div#menuJQ ul ul div {
      width: 180px;
      padding: 0;
    background: url(../includes/images/subsubmenu-top.png) no-repeat 0px 0;
    -background: url(../includes/images/subsubmenu-top.gif) no-repeat 0px 0;      
    margin: -32px 0 0 198px !important;
    margin: -32px 0 0 176px;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul ul {
    padding: 11px 0px 9px 0px;  
    margin: 20px 0 0 0; 
}
div#menuJQ ul ul div li {
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
}

/* lava lamp */
div#menuJQ li.back {
    background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    -background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.gif) no-repeat 0 0;    
    width: 5px;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
}


div#menuJQ li.back .left {
    padding:0;
    width:auto;
    background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.png) repeat-x right 0;
    -background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.gif) repeat-x right 0;     
    height: 46px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('#menuJQ > ul li').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('ul:first', this).show("fast").siblings().hide("fast");
        });
    });
    $('.submenu').mouseleave(function() {
        $('ul', this).hide("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Javascript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#menuJQ').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.submenu').find('ul').css('display', 'none'); //display none all submenus
        $('ul:first', this).show("fast").siblings().hide("fast");
    });

    $('.submenu').on('mouseleave', 'ul', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide("fast");
    });

});
```

Here is a JS fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/2SC5G/3/

Comment: thanks for your help, but now when you click in the submenu it automatically disappears. Try to go to SEARCH > RESULTS you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Oh sorry about that i didn't test it properly. 
I've had another go and I've changed a few classes in the main menu html so the show submenu event is not triggered by the buttons in the sub menu its self.
http://jsfiddle.net/2SC5G/5/

Comment: thanks! I simply changed this "$('.submenu').mouseleave(function()" to this "$('#menuJQ > ul li').mouseleave(function()" and it works great. I will try your example for comparison.